# How does python-glove compute most similar?

Tags: python, similarities, word2vec

i am trying to understand how python-glove computes `most-similar` terms.

Is it using cosine similarity?

Example from python-glove github
https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/tree/master/glove
:[image]

I know that from gensim's word2vec, the `most_similar` method computes similarity using cosine distance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, python-glove also computes the cosine similarity. In `_similarity_query` it performs these operations:

```
dst = (np.dot(self.word_vectors, word_vec)
               / np.linalg.norm(self.word_vectors, axis=1)
               / np.linalg.norm(word_vec))
```

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/blob/749494290fdfd24379dcc2e244c583ee61808634/glove/glove.py#L273) if no updates have been performed (otherwise search for the `_similarity_query`).

As you can observe, the function first computes the `dot` product between the word vectors and the current word embedding, after that the division between the norms (or length) is performed, which corresponds to the definition of the **cosine** distance $$\text{CosineSimilarity(u, v)} = \frac {u . v} {||u||_2 ||v||_2} = cos(\theta) \tag{1}$$
.